# Huffman tree on characters in python

Tags: python, algorithm, huffman-code

I want to Create a list of postfix-free code like Huffman code but on characters. For example:

```
a ~~> Word with high Frequency
.
.
.
baz ~~> Word with lower Frequency
```

I use this function in python for generate characters sequence

```
def iter_all_strings():
    size = 1
    while True:
        for s in itertools.product(ascii_lowercase, repeat=size):
            yield "".join(s)
        size +=1
```

but they are not prefix-free, How can I do that ?

Comment: Your question is not clear. If you want a prefix-tree, implement a prefix tree.

Comment: @Sorin No I want a *Prefix Free* like Huffman but I think this tree contains 52 leafes because 26 lower case + 26 uppercase . I want to sure that how can i translate to main string for example : `a --> b` and `aa--> c` if i want to translate `aaa` there is two option and its ambigious. How can i make uniqe shortest character like huffman proccess?